# Methods calls sequence visualization (diagram) in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, sequence, visualization

Is it possible to see method's call's sequence visualization (diagram) in InteliJ Idea when I use debug mode? Thanks!

Comment: I want see a calls of all custom methods of project.

Comment: It is not one method but all.

Comment: Check https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286-sequencediagram.